# What's the alternative manuallly restarting a Work manager Worker

Tags: android, kotlin

WorkManager API doesn't provide a dedicated restart worker method. Is there a good way to restart a failed worker which has chained workers as well?

For example let's assume we have 3 workers in a chain A->B->C and any of them can fail.

What's the proper way to rebuild the chain since there is no restart method? Assume also that the restart is not synchronous which means that it will happen after user triggered it and not in some specific time frame.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I went with manually recreating the chain based on the available database state

Comment: Ahh, my issue is I don't have the user on the app while my Worker is running, 
Can you take a [look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76700429/listenableworkers-onstopped-gets-called-unexpectedly-while-executing-code) in case you have any suggestions, TIA

Answer (score 0):

There is [Retry and Backoff policy](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work#retry_and_backoff_policy) in work manager for retrying your work in case of any error or if you want to retry your work in any case. For details on chained workers retry strategies [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/chain-work#work-statuses) is the link.

Comment: That won't work. The delay is not expressed in terms of time as I described but rather on user action.