# ListenableWorker's onStopped() gets called unexpectedly while executing code

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-workmanager, android-background

Short Story :
I have a `ListenableWorker` that performs tasks involving fetching data from a local database and performing checks with this data. However, I have noticed that the `onStopped()` method of the worker is sometimes called while my code is still executing. This raises concerns about potential problems during long-running tasks that may span 12-18 hours. I'm unsure how this could happen and if it might cause issues for keeping the worker alive.

Long Story :
In my application I need to run a task for user-defined duration at a user-selected start time.

For Example : A user can specify running this task fom 10:00 P.M. for Half an hour 
or from 9 A.M. for 12 hours,
Both the start time and duration are selected by the user

To handle this, I store the start time and duration in a local Database using `Room` and utilize WorkManager/Alarms to initiate the work.

Previously, I used a [Foreground Notification Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) for long-running tasks, but due to [restrictions introduced in Android 12](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#background-start-restrictions), I'm migrating to WorkManager.

My current approach for managing a WorkManager's Listenable Worker and keeping it alive for the specified duration is as follows:

- My Worker is of type `ListenableWorker` which I am using with a `ResolvableFuture<Result>`, which is being returned from startWork() since it takes `ListenableFuture<Result>` as return type

- In `startWork()` I fetch data from Room Database, perform various checks and apply logic

- I also register a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen to specific user actions.

- And if everything is in order, I call `setForegroundAsync()` to keep the worker running and show a notification to the user using the same.

- If I need to stop the worker before completing the entire task, I use `set(Result.failure())` on the `ResolvableFuture<Result>` returned from `startWork()`.

- I use a `Handler()` with a delayed `Runnable` which is triggered after the user-specified duration and after the specified duration, I call `set(Result.Success())` on the same `ResolvableFuture<Result>` to stop the worker.

Now I have two concerns:

1) I'm uncertain if this approach is suitable for my use case and if there are alternative options for handling this kind of long-running work from the background.

2) I'm facing an issue where the onStopped() callback of the ListenableWorker is invoked while my code is still executing.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on why this might occur and if there are improvements or alternative approaches I should consider.

Thank you in advance for any assistance or guidance you can provide.